# Why can't I just delete the header row from a CSV file?

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm having the hardest time deleting a header row for a CSV file.

This is some code that I wrote to generate a list of account ids from a third-party email service that determines if an account is valid or not.

This is the CSV generator code:

```
CSV.foreach('complete_failed_list.csv', {headers: false}) do |failed_csv_list|
  CSV.open("failed_id_list.csv", "a", {headers: false}) do |csv|
    csv << [failed_csv_list[0]]
  end
end
```

This creates a CSV file with the following format:

```
id
1
2
3
```

I don't want the `id` header but, even though I specify `headers: false`, there still is a header! I want to get rid of it but I can't manually delete it because I'm on a Mac and I have to save the file as a Numbers ".numbers" file instead of ".csv".

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Ruby CSV file". They are just CSV files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the `headers` option tells Ruby whether or not you expect your data to have headers, and if you set `headers: true` you can actually access columns in your data by the header's name. See "[A Guide to the Ruby CSV Library, Part II](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-csv-library-part-2/)" for some more details.

However, you are still iterating over every row in the data and so you are dumping the header row into your target file. From the [`CSV.foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) documentation:

> Each row of the file will be passed to the provided `block` in turn.

Something I have often done is to set a flag to skip the headers before iterating, then jump over the first step:

```
skip_headers = true

CSV.foreach('complete_failed_list.csv') do |failed_csv_list|
    if skip_headers
        skip_headers = false  # Make sure to change the flag or you will skip every row
        next  # Move to the next step in the iteration
    end

  CSV.open("failed_id_list.csv", "a") do |csv|
    csv << [failed_csv_list[0]]
  end
end
```

I have also tried to find a more "Ruby-way" to do this, as it seems simple enough but I have not found one better than this basic approach.

Comment: Thank god. I can't believe there is no easy way to just skip the header. Thanks for this answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: @DanRubio Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the csv `headers` options only determines whether or not the returned results row come back as an array or a hash which is keyed by the first row in the csv. By setting `{ headers: true }` you essentially skip the header row but have to access the values using a key instead of an index. See below.

```
CSV.foreach('complete_failed_list.csv', {headers: true}) do |failed_csv_list|
  CSV.open("failed_id_list.csv", "a", {headers: false}) do |csv|
    csv << [failed_csv_list['id']]
  end
end
```

More information on what options are accepted can be found [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new). I played around with the `return_headers` option as well but it didn't seem to matter in terms of what foreach iterates over.